# LibGit2Sharp equivalent of git diff --stat

Tags: libgit2, libgit2sharp

I'm looking for a way to capture how many lines have changed in each file in my working directory - like `git diff --stat` in git - is there a way to do this with LibGit2Sharp?

I know I can get total LinesAdded/Deleted from a Patch, but I'm wondering on a file by file basis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following will enumerate all the files that have been changed between two commits, along with the number of changes (global, line additions and line removals).

```
var patch = repo.Diff.Compare<Patch>(fromCommit, untilCommit);

foreach (var pec in patch)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1} ({2}+ and {3}-)",
        pec.Path,
        pec.LinesAdded + pec.LinesDeleted,
        pec.LinesAdded,
        pec.LinesDeleted);
}
```

Would you need to access a specific file within a `Patch`, the types exposes an indexer to ease that

```
PatchEntryChanges entryChanges = patch["path/to/my/file.txt"];
```

Comment: Genius! Exactly what I needed - thanks!  And thanks for the extra tidbit about accessing that file too!

Comment: Hi @nultoken, can you help me on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30214314/3497987)

Comment: @Carlos Looks like you've perfectly dealt with your issue! Cheers.